# How do I send HTTP content length header to client using socket programming in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, http, tcp

I am new to tcp client-server programming and was just struggling with this. Could someone please guide me? Thank You in advance. I am trying to display content length dynamically when I connect to a server using telnet.

```
char *body = "hickory dickory dock"; (Example). 

int val = strlen(body);

reqType = "GET";
printf("%s\n", buffer);
     if(checkRequest(reqType, buffer)){
          char *response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: ";
           write(new_socket , response , strlen(response));
           write(new_socket, val, sizeof(int));
           char *m = "\n\n";
           write(new_socket, m, strlen(m));
           write(new_socket, body, strlen(body));
        }
```

Comment: Please, also provide the output you got and the output you expect. Side note: in HTTP/1.1, the correct way to end the line is `\r\n`, not `\n` (double end of line is therefore `\r\n\r\n`).

Comment: As far as I can see, the main problem with the code presented is that you are sending a binary representation of the content length, whereas HTTP expects a text representation.  Format it as text (with `sprintf()`, for example) and send it like you are sending other strings.

Comment: You need to send the length as a *string*. When you use `write(new_socket, val, sizeof(int));` you send the raw binary value of `val` not its string representation. Use e.g. `snprintf` to create a string that you can send.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  and John Bollinger got it to work, thank you so much! I tried snprintf earlier but ended up having using this "snprintf(valuestring, %s, val)" which was causing a segmentation fault. Just realised that I needed to use the data type of val as the middle parameter in order for it to work. Once again Thank you so much!

Comment: I would rather do something like `char response[4096]; snprintf(response, sizeof response, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/plain\r\nContent-length: %zu\r\n\r\n%s\r\n", strlen(body), body); write(new_socket, response, strlen(response));`